# Object serialization for a new activity

Tags: android, serialization, android-activity, xamarin, bundle

I am coding in Xamarin and I need to pass an object to another activity, however I am getting an error in relation to converting the object to an 'Android.OS.Bundle'

Here are the errors:

> The best overloaded method match for 'Android.Content.Intent.PutExtra(string, Android.OS.Bundle)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'SimpleMapDemo.TestObjectToSerialize' to 'Android.OS.Bundle'

Here is the code I am using to pass the object to another activity:

```
TestObjectToSerialize testObjectToSerialize;
testObjectToSerialize.testString = "objectToSerialize";
Intent intent = new Intent (this.ApplicationContext, typeof(HomeScreen));
intent.PutExtra("objectToSerialize", testObjectToSerialize);
```

Here is the class:

```
[Serializable]
class TestObjectToSerialize
{
    public string testString{ set; get;}
}
```

May I please have some help to get this code working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do that. First of all, I recommend not to pass the object as extra. Instead you can use "Singleton pattern" - just define static class with static property of the same type you want to pass, and just assign passing object to this static property.
But if you really need to pass it as extra, you can use serialization and to serialize to any type of object. Here's a quick sample (note, to simplify the example I'm not closing streams and not doing code reusing - it's just an example, so you can understand the principles).
In my "MainActivity" on some button click event, I'm adding this code:

```
var testObj = new TestObjectToSerialize();
testObj.testString = "testString";
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(stream, testObj);

var secondActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
secondActivity.PutExtra("testObj", stream.ToArray());
StartActivity(secondActivity);
```

In SecondActivity, I'm receiving the extra like this:

```
var byteArr = Intent.GetByteArrayExtra("testObj");
var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArr);
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var testObj = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as TestObjectToSerialize;

Toast.MakeText(this, testObj.testString, ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

You can use any kind of serialization here. You also can implement `Java.IO.ISerializable`.
First of all, add `Mono.Android.Export.dll` into your project references. Now, in your `TestObjectToSerialize` add this using:

`using Java.Interop;`

Now modify your class like this:

```
public class TestObjectToSerialize : Java.Lang.Object, Java.IO.ISerializable
{
    public string testString { set; get; }

    //The magic starts here

    public TestObjectToSerialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestObjectToSerialize..ctor");
    }

    //You have to make this one
    public TestObjectToSerialize(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(handle, transfer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestObjectToSerialize..ctor(IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership)");
    }

    [Export("readObject", Throws = new[] {
    typeof (Java.IO.IOException),
    typeof (Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException)})]
    private void ReadObjectDummy(Java.IO.ObjectInputStream source)
    {
        testString = ReadNullableString(source);
    }

    [Export("writeObject", Throws = new[] {
    typeof (Java.IO.IOException),
    typeof (Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException)})]
    private void WriteObjectDummy(Java.IO.ObjectOutputStream destination)
    {
        WriteNullableString(destination, testString);
    }

    static void WriteNullableString(Java.IO.ObjectOutputStream dest, string value)
    {
        dest.WriteBoolean(value != null);
        if (value != null)
            dest.WriteUTF(value);
    }

    static string ReadNullableString(Java.IO.ObjectInputStream source)
    {
        if (source.ReadBoolean())
            return source.ReadUTF();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, in `MainActivity` you can do this:

```
var testObj = new TestObjectToSerialize();
testObj.testString = "testString";

var secondActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
secondActivity.PutExtra("testObj", testObj);
StartActivity(secondActivity);
```

And in `SecondActivity` this:

```
var testObj = Intent.GetSerializableExtra("testObj") as TestObjectToSerialize;
Toast.MakeText(this, testObj.testString, ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

Good luck =)